# Двадцать один хорош(?) год - declension after number 21

Tags: прилагательные, склонение, числительные

EN: I know that number 21 (in nominative) demands nominative singular (21 год) and, although number 22 (in nominative) would demand genitive singular from the upcoming noun (22 года), an adjective describing "22 года" would demand genitive plural. Thus, "22 хороших года".

But, I have one doubt. What case do adjectives after "21" take?

Would it be 21 хороших год? 21 хорошего года? 21 хорошие год? Or none of the aforementioned?

Thanks for your help.

PS: And if 21 itself is declined - like двадцати одного (genitive), for example - do upcoming words all take genitive plural?

RU: Я знаю, что, после числа "22", прилагательное принимает множественное число/родительный падеж, и имя "год" принимает единственное число/родительный падеж.

Так что, будет "22 хороших года".

Но, если число - 21, то какой падеж слова "хороший"? 
21 хорош(?) год.

Спасибо за помощь.

PS: Если число 21 само употребляет склонение (родительный падеж - двадцати одного?), следующие слова употребляют ли множественное число/то склонение числа?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the numerals ending in 1, *exept* for those that end in 11 (11, 111, 711, 1011, etc.), need the following noun in the Nominatve case singular. If there is also an attribute adjective, it agrees with the noun in gender, case, and number, that is the adjective will also be in the Nominatve case singular:

> 21 good girls — двадцать одна хорошая девочка
>
> 21 good years — двадцать один хороший год

Note, here *both* the numeral and the adjective are *attributes* of the noun, so if we change the case of the noun, both the numeral and the adjective get the same case as the noun:

> **Nom.:** двадцать один хороший год
>
> **Gen.:** двадцати одного хорошего года
>
> **Dat.:** двадцати одному хорошему году
>
> **Acc.:** двадцать один хороший год
>
> **Instr.:** двадцатью одним хорошим годом
>
> **Prep.:** (о) двадцати одном хорошем годе
>
> **Locat.:** (в) двадцати одном хорошем году

Comment: Ваш родной язык русский, точно? Ну, спасибо огромное за помощь. Сейчас сомнение мне стало ясным. Значит, числительные, кончающие по ...1 (кроме тех, кончающие по ...11), требуют всегда единственное число, по всем склонениям. > (Кстати, я заметил "двадцатью одним хоро**шиим** годом". Коротко я
> думал, что было множественное число/творительный падеж, а потом я
> заметил, что это опечатка) Ещё раз, спасибо за быстрый ответ!